# The boundary of connected component of complement of compact set

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

if $K$ is a compact set of $\mathbb{C}$, the connected components of $\mathbb{C}\backslash K$ are connected open sets of $\mathbb{C}$, that is, a countable quantity of domains of $\mathbb{C}$. Every component $C$ of $\mathbb{C}\backslash K$ satisfies the condition that $\partial C\subset K$ where $\partial C$ denote the boundary of $C$ .

How to proof this result .I need the proofs of such result.I will be thankful if someone can suggest me some reference book for the proof of such kind of results.

Comment: What have you tried? What about the easy parts, e.g. that $\Bbb C\setminus K$ is the union of connected open sets (ignoring for now the part to show that there are countably many). This almost follows from the definitions. What about that $\partial C\cap C=\varnothing$? Also where is this question from? Give us some contex in order to better understand what is or should be your knowledge here. The basics to prove something like this will be found in any introduction into metric spaces, topology or higher-dimensional analysis.

Comment: Dear I am working in complex analysis .May be it is easy problem but I have not enough background to prove this.I have seen some examples but the point is how to prove this one. Similarly I know that If $U$ is open set then the boundary of connected component of it complement will not intersect with $U$

Answer (score 4):

Since $K$ is compact, it is closed. Therefore $\bar K:=\Bbb C\setminus K$ is open.

> **Proposition 1**. Connected component of open sets are open.

*Proof*.

Let $C\subseteq\bar K$ a connected component of $\bar K$. Choose some $x\in C$. Then $x\in \bar K$ and we can choose some $\epsilon>0$ so that  $U_\epsilon(x)\subseteq \bar K$. Since $U_\epsilon(x)$ is connected, it is completely contained in the same connected component as $x$, hence $x\in U_\epsilon(x)\subseteq C$. Thus $C$ is open. $\square$

> **Proposition 2**. $U_i,i\in I$ are pair-wise disjoint open sets in $\Bbb C$, then $I$ is at most countable.

*Proof*.

$\Bbb C$ is [second countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-countable_space), i.e. there are countably many open sets $V_j,j\in J$ so that any open set in $\Bbb C$ can be written as the union of some $V_j$. For exmaple, choose the countably many open sets $U_\epsilon(x)$ with $\epsilon\in\Bbb Q^+$ and $x\in\Bbb Q[i]=\{a+ib\mid a,b\in\Bbb Q\}$.

Now, this means that every $U_i$ is the union of some of these $V_j$. Also, no two different disjoint $U_i$ share the same $V_j$. This means that each of the $U_i$ represents a group of $V_j$, and all the groups are disjoint. But since there are only countably many $V_j$, we cannot partition them into uncountably many disjoint groups. Hence there are at most countably many $U_i$. $\square$

This proves the first part, namely, that $\bar K$ is the union of countably many connected open sets. The open sets in question are just the connected components of $\bar K$. That these are open is shown in Proposition 1. That there are at most countably many is shown in Proposition 2.

> **Proposition 3**. If $A,B\subset \Bbb C$ are two disjoint open sets, then $\partial A\cap B=\varnothing$.

*Proof*.

If $x\in B$, then there is some $U_\epsilon(x)\subseteq B$. But when also $x\in\partial A$, then every such $U_\epsilon(x)$ must intersect $A$. This contradicts that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint. $\square$

This shows the second part. An open set does not contain any of its boundary points (by definition). Hence $\partial C\cap C=\varnothing$. Now, if $D\subseteq\bar K$ is another one of these open connected components of $\bar K$, then Proposition 3 shows that $\partial C\cap D=\varnothing$. Hence the complete boundary must be in $K$.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the detailed answer.Can you suggest me the name of any Topological book?

Comment: And is that correct $\mathbb{C}\backslash K$ has only one unbounded component? And please tell me some reference book.

Comment: @muhammadmohsin Yes, that is true. Unfortunately, I cannot recommend any specific book, since I learned math from many partial sources. It seems what you need are the definitions (which you can find on wikipedia) and some good practice in giving proofs.